# Lock-free concurrent field usage

Tags: multithreading, rust, concurrency, automatic-ref-counting

Say I have the following struct:

```
struct MyStruct {
   field1: Box<MyField>,
   field2: Box<MyField>,
}
```

and I'd like to be able to do the following:

1. Use the fields in separate threads in a mutable fashion.
2. Wait until complete
3. Then start using the struct as a whole.

In theory, a reference counted type is sufficient (i.e. no locks).

To illustrate, here's some broken code that demonstrates the problem:

```
// Function to call when everything's done.
fn all_done(s: MyStruct) {
    ...
}

// Holds MyStruct until all references are dropped and then calls `all_done`
struct Guard(Option<MyStruct>);

impl Guard {
    fn new(s: MyStruct) -> Self {
        Self(Some(s))
    }
}

impl Drop for Guard {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        all_done(self.0.take().unwrap());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s: MyStruct = ...;
    let f1 = &mut s.field1;
    let f2 = &mut s.field2;
    let s = Arc::new(Guard::new(s));

    let s_copy = s.clone();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        do_some_mutating_with(f1);
        drop(s_copy);
    });

    thread::spawn(move || {
        do_some_mutating_with(f2);
        drop(s);
    });
}
```

In this contrived example, a few things are worth noting:

1. The references don't outlive the value. This is ensured because the threads hold an `Arc` instance for that value.
2. No part of the struct is used concurrently in multiple threads.

The compiler complains because:

1. `Arc::new(Guard::new(s))` moves something that's borrowed. On the other hand, if we created the thing in the `Arc` from the get-go, we'd have a different problem: "cannot borrow data in an `Arc` as mutable". Certainly, the references shouldn't be to the value on the stack as they are above.
2. It's not convinced the references live long enough.

Is there any way to restructure the code to accomplish what it's trying to do? Absent that, are there any libraries that enable something equivalent?

Comment: I think patterns like this are fundamentally incompatible with Rust's borrowing model. You can fix the issue by wrapping both fields of `MyStruct` in `Mutex`es but that's in opposition to your stated goal of being lock-free. Theoretically you could make this work with `Arc::get_mut` and using pointers with `unsafe` blocks to dereference them, but that's playing with fire. As an example of how easy it is to create bugs in that kind of code, the code in your question would exhibit UB if Rust allowed it to compile, as `f1` and `f2` are orphan references after `s` is moved into the `Guard`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @Jmb does answer the question, but is limited to spawning new threads. The original question did spawn new threads, but more for explanatory purposes. The goal was to work in async Rust and other contexts in which doing that each time is not an option.

Turns out the key to making this work is "interior mutability", which replaces compile-time guarantees for runtime checks. Instead of references, I can use something like [crossbeam::atomic::AtomicCell](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/latest/crossbeam/atomic/struct.AtomicCell.html).

Here's a rough sketch of a solution:

```
use crossbeam::atomic::AtomicCell;
use std::{sync::Arc, thread};

struct MyStruct {
    field1: AtomicCell<Option<Box<i32>>>,
    field2: AtomicCell<Option<Box<i32>>>,
}

fn all_done(s: MyStruct) {
    println!(
        "Done: field1={}, field2={}",
        s.field1.swap(None).unwrap(),
        s.field2.swap(None).unwrap(),
    );
}

struct Guard(Option<MyStruct>);

impl Guard {
    fn new(s: MyStruct) -> Self {
        Self(Some(s))
    }
}

impl Drop for Guard {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        all_done(self.0.take().unwrap());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = MyStruct {
        field1: AtomicCell::new(Some(Box::new(0))),
        field2: AtomicCell::new(Some(Box::new(0))),
    };
    let s = Arc::new(Guard::new(s));

    let s_copy = s.clone();
    let jh1 = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut f1 = s_copy.0.as_ref().unwrap().field1.swap(None).unwrap();
        *f1 = 1;
        s_copy.0.as_ref().unwrap().field1.swap(Some(f1));
    });

    let jh2 = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut f2 = s.0.as_ref().unwrap().field2.swap(None).unwrap();
        *f2 = 2;
        s.0.as_ref().unwrap().field2.swap(Some(f2));
    });

    jh1.join().unwrap();
    jh2.join().unwrap();
}
```

[Rust Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a2d138bed2d9cac52c5316abb117a654)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with scoped threads:

```
use std::thread;

#[derive (Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
   field1: Box<i32>,
   field2: Box<i32>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = MyStruct {
        field1: Box::new (0),
        field2: Box::new (0),
    };
    let f1 = &mut s.field1;
    let f2 = &mut s.field2;
    thread::scope (move |s| {
        s.spawn (|| { **f1 = 42; });
        s.spawn (|| { **f2 = 24; });
    });
    println!("{s:?}");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=d0ca1e407b88c69ea10f65ca39d41b3f)

Comment: You can use `Box::as_mut()` to get direct references so you can use a single `*` to update the data: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=bbeff794ea47feb24afec7df9c4b5b79